# Code trouble with python

Tags: python, math

I'm having some trouble here. For my CS assignment, I have to have python take data from a file on my pc and run the data through my program.

So, this code works fine on http://repl.it/languages/Python, but not in python. I'm assuming because my line of code has some Python 2.0 lines of code? I can't seem to fix it. Can you guys help? And, another small question except this one. I have to input some code in my program to take data from a file and run it through my program as I stated above. I have this.

```
    import math

def mean(values):
    average = sum(values)*1.0/len(values)
    return average

def deviation(values):
    length = len(values)
    m = mean(values)
    total_sum = 0

    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += (values[i]-m)**2

    root = total_sum*1.0/length
    return math.sqrt(root)

def median(values):
    if len(values)%2 != 0:
        return sorted(values)[len(values)/2]
    else:
        midavg = (sorted(values)[len(values)/2] + sorted(values)[len(values)/2-1])/2.0
        return midavg

def main():
    x = [15, 17, 40, 16, 9]
    print mean(x)
    print deviation(x)
    print median(x)

main()
```

How do I specifically have the program take data from the file and run it through my program? The data is just a bunch of numbers, by the way. It's been giving me trouble for some hours now. Thanks if you can help out.

This is what I know about the opening/closing file stuff so far

```
 f = open("filename.txt")
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Comment: How *exactly* does this code currently fail?

Comment: Syntax error at "Print mean(x), and deviation and median". it fails there

Comment: @Matty In python 3.0, you need to print something as `print(x)` while in python 2.x, you can write `print x`.

Comment: But I defined mean, median, and standard dev. So, how would I get the program to print the solution for each one? Brain farts right now.

Comment: @Matty oh, I meant that you may need to write `print(mean(x))` instead of `print mean(x)` in case you're coding in python 3.

Comment: Print changed between Python 2 and Python 3, in Python 3 it must be written as though it were a function. This is why it is useful to include the version of Python that you are using in your questions.

Comment: Thanks! But now Im getting a syntax error.           19.4
10.669582934679312
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mkinic1/Desktop/M,M,SD.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/mkinic1/Desktop/M,M,SD.py", line 29, in main
    print(median(x))
  File "C:/Users/mkinic1/Desktop/M,M,SD.py", line 20, in median
    return sorted(values)[len(values)/2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
>>>

Comment: I realized that using the / division was more of python 2x and in python three, true division is //. So, I added another / to my divisions, but the number im getting now is 16... Is that correct?def median(values):
    if len(values)%2 != 0:
        return sorted(values)[len(values)//2]
    else:
        midavg = (sorted(values)[len(values)//2] + sorted(values)[len(values)//2-1])//2.0
    return midavg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are using [python2.x](/questions/tagged/python2.x):

> I'm assuming because my line of code has some Python 2.0 lines of code?

So yes, you *do* have a problem: In [python3.x](/questions/tagged/python3.x)[, `print` became a function.](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

Thus, your `print`s need to be changed:

```
print mean(x)
print deviation(x)
print median(x)
```

Becomes

```
print(mean(x))
print(deviation(x))
print(median(x))
```

<sup>Also, your part about opening and closing files is unclear.</sup>

Comment: Thanks bud! I inputted that, and it seems to work fine. Now, since I finally cleared that up, he also wants to add an addition to the code. Instead of the user inputting data constantly, he wants us to write some lines of code in the program that has python take data from a file that has data(just numbers) already pre-written, and runs the numbers through the mean, median, and standard dev equations

Comment: Opening and closing files. I'm a beginner at it and I didn't understand much of what my professor said, regardless of my questions. I have to have my progam open a file and read the data from the file into my program, and run it through the mean, standard deviation, and median equations. The .txt file just contains numbers for the code to use, but I'm having trouble even starting it because I just started learning it.